# Solving Inequalities in Sympy

Tags: python, sympy

I tried to solve the following inequality in sympy:

```
(10000 / x) - 1 < 0
```

So I issued the command:

```
solve_poly_inequality( Poly((10000 / x) - 1 ), '<')
```

However, I got:

```
[Interval.open(-oo, 1/10000)]
```

However, my manual computations give either x < 0 or x > 10000.

What am I missing? Due to the -1, I cannot represent it as a rational function.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You are using a low-level solving routine. I would recommend using the higher-level routines `solve` or `solveset`, e.g.

```
>>> solveset((10000 / x) - 1 < 0, x, S.Reals)
(−∞, 0) ∪ (10000, ∞)
```

The reason that your attempt is right but looks wrong is that you did not specify the generator to use so Poly used `1/x` as its variable (let's call it `g`) so it solved the problem `1000*g - 1 < 0`...which is true when g is less than 1/1000 as you found.

You can see this generator identification by writing

```
>>> Poly(1000/x - 1).gens
(1/x,)
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you! It's a pity that sympy has such a bad documentation. I have come across solveset several times, but never managed to understand its docs. Now it's clear. Also the reason that I was attracted of `solve_poly_inequality` was its `solve_poly_inequalities` variant for systems of inequalities. Thanks again!

Comment: @OlliD-Metz if you have an idea on how that part of the documentation can be improved any contribution would almost certainly be most welcomed (no matter how small).

Comment: Well, I did not find a basic documentation of the `Poly` command. So, if someone is missing the basics, everything that follows can only be very complicated. If you search the web for "sympy solve inequality", you end up here: http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/solvers/inequalities.html, with no remark that one should better just use solveset (which is also much more comfortable)

Answer (score 3):

`10000/x-1` is not a polynomial in `x` but a polynomial in `1/x`. Rather, `10000/x-1` is a [rational function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_function) in `x`. While you may try to put `Poly(1000*1/x - 1, x, domain='ZZ')`, there will be errors

```
PolynomialError: 1/x contains an element of the generators set
```

because by definition `10000/x-1` cannot be a polynomial in `x`. Thus, you just cannot do the computation with this.

You can also try to following or other solvers.

```
from sympy.solvers.inequalities import reduce_rational_inequalities
from sympy import Poly
from sympy.abc import x
reduce_rational_inequalities([[10000/x - 1 < 0]], x)
((-oo < x) & (x < 0)) | ((10000 < x) & (x < oo))
```